# ShowDialogの後に処理する方法

Tags: powershell

PowerShellで `$form.ShowDialog()` すると、そこで処理が完全に止まってしまいます。
ShowDialogの1秒後にWrite-Host "hoge"を処理するには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

ShowDialogの代わりにShow()を使うと、フォームのウィンドウがフリーズしました。

・やりたいこと
メインとなるフォームを表示させ、1秒後に、コンソールにhogeと表示する。

Comment: ShowDialogの代わりにShowを使えば、少なくともモーダルにはならないはずですが、コードが提示されていないので、こちらで確認ができません。"ShowDialogの代わりにShow()を使うと、フォームのウィンドウがフリーズしました" 現象が再現するコードを質問文に追記できないでしょうか。

Comment: こんな記事が応用できるのでは？ [PowerShellでストップウォッチを自作する](https://commercialising67.rssing.com/chan-63260048/latest-article1-live.php)

Comment: 上記ストップウォッチのサイトを参考にして、Timer.Elapsedとかを使うと、できそうな感じでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

特にWinFormsの場合、いきなりPowerShellで試行錯誤するのではなく、C#で実装してからPowerShellに移植することをお勧めします。

今回の質問でも`Form.Show()`、`Form.ShowDialog()`が取り上げられていますが、C#で実装すれば、`Program.cs`の`Main()`メソッドに

```cs
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

と書かれるわけで、PowerShellでも対応する処理を書く必要があることに気づけるはずですし、この行を実行するとフォームが閉じられるまで返ってこないことも理解できるはずです。

> メインとなるフォームを表示させ、1秒後に、コンソールにhogeと表示する。

上記の通りなので、フォーム内のいずれかのメソッドで出力する必要があります。